# c# listbox fed List acting very weird

Tags: c#, list, listbox, datasource

Ok so I have this function which clears a list by choise made in gui and feeds with newly selected... its very simple : a class which has a constructor and an overrided ToString method is thrown into a List and served as datasource for the listbox ... any test i make, this works flawlessly, but not in this specific program, and i can't figure out why. Im not desperate, im just really curious.

I found that if i simply convert the List<> to an array it works... but why ?

This is my original code that doesn't work:

```
private void QaControl(string _itemNo, int _curIndex)
    {
        List<QaControlPoint> list = new List<QaControlPoint>();

        //remove old ones from list 
        if (listBox1.DataSource != null)
        {
            list = (List<QaControlPoint>)listBox1.DataSource;

            for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                QaControlPoint qcp = (QaControlPoint)listBox1.Items[n];
                if (_boxList.IndexOf(qcp.link_box) >= _curIndex)
                    list.Remove(qcp);
            }
        }

        string fs = service.getQa(Int32.Parse(_itemNo), "R");
        string[] temp = fs.Split('@');
        for (int a = 0; a < temp.Length - 1; a++)
            list.Add(new QaControlPoint(temp[a], _boxList[_curIndex]));
        listBox1.DataSource = list;
    }
```

this code , where i use simple array as datasource works perfect.

```
private void QaControl(string _itemNo, int _curIndex)
    {
        List<QaControlPoint> list1 = new List<QaControlPoint>();

        //remove old ones from list 
        if (listBox1.DataSource != null)
        {
            //convert to list here
            QaControlPoint[] rcp = (QaControlPoint[])listBox1.DataSource;
            list1.AddRange(rcp);

            QaControlPoint rcp2;
            for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                rcp2 = (QaControlPoint)listBox1.Items[n];
                if (_boxList.IndexOf(rcp2.link_box) >= _curIndex)
                    list1.Remove(rcp2);
            }
        }

        string fs = service.getQa(Int32.Parse(_itemNo), "R");
        string[] temp = fs.Split('@');
        for (int a = 0; a < temp.Length - 1; a++)
            list1.Add(new QaControlPoint(temp[a], _boxList[_curIndex]));

        //convert back to array here
        QaControlPoint[] rcnew = list1.ToArray();
        listBox1.DataSource = rcnew;
    }
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "doesn't work" - doesn't show any items?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, here, but in the first example the DataSource property is never changed. Sure, you are adding and removing items, but when you set the DataSource, you are setting it to the same object instance it already had.

In the second example, you are using a new instance (both a new List, then again a new Array).

My guess is that the ListBox is smart enough to recognize that you are not changing the value of the DataSource when you are setting to the same instance, so it's not performing the very expensive step of refreshing itself. This looks like WinForms, with which I am not very familiar, but I do not think that `List<T>` implements the necessary interfaces for the ListBox to catch collection changed events.

Try this instead:

```
    private void QaControl( string _itemNo, int _curIndex ) {
        List<QaControlPoint> list = new List<QaControlPoint>();

        //remove old ones from list         
        if ( listBox1.DataSource != null ) {
            List<QaControlPoint> oldList = (List<QaControlPoint>) listBox1.DataSource;
            list.AddRange( oldList );
            for ( int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n ) {
                QaControlPoint qcp = (QaControlPoint) listBox1.Items[n];
                if ( _boxList.IndexOf( qcp.link_box ) >= _curIndex )
                    list.Remove( qcp );
            }
        }

        string fs = service.getQa( Int32.Parse( _itemNo ), "R" );
        string[] temp = fs.Split( '@' );
        for ( int a = 0; a < temp.Length - 1; a++ )
            list.Add( new QaControlPoint( temp[a], _boxList[_curIndex] ) );
        listBox1.DataSource = list;
    }
```